# Чтение файла. Строки. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы, текстовые-файлы

условно есть файл `test.txt` с контентом

```
Hello\n\nHi
```

делаю чтение следующим образом

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

получаю строку в формате
`Hello\n\nHi`

собственно, я бы хотел получить в результате с переносом строк, а не в виде символов `\n`

Comment: Как воспроизвести ваш результат? Ваш код дает именно тот результат, который вам нужен - с переносом строк, а не с `\n`

Comment: @zxnuclear прошу прощения, изменил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью `replace` заменить

```
with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  print(f.read().replace('\\n', '\n'))
```

На входе имеем `Hello\n\nHi\nTest string\nOne more`, на выходе получаем

```
Hello

Hi
Test string
One more
```

Comment: спасибо, работает как надо)